# Ruby - Pass JSON object and keys to function

Tags: json, ruby

I'm just trying to create a helper function that'll attempt to get a value out of "ohai_data" 
and return a default value if it's not found.

"ohai_data " is:

```
ohai_data = JSON.parse(::IO.read(json_file).force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_16))
```

The data is in this format:

```
{
    "kernel": {
        "os_info": {
            "cs_name": "<the computer name>"
        }
    }
}
```

e.g.

## This works:

```
ohai_data['kernel']['os_info']['cs_name']
```

## This does not:

```
def get_val(val_to_get, ohai_data, default_val)    
    val = ohai_data[val_to_get]
    val = val.to_s
    if val.nil? or val.empty?
        puts "#{val_to_get} not found within ohai_data.  Using default value: #{default_val}"
        val = default_val
    end
    puts "Getting #{val_to_get} from ohai_data:  #{val}"
    return val.chomp
end

machine_name = get_val("['kernel']['os_info']['cs_name']", ohai_data, 'n/a')
```

## I've tried various things:

no implicit conversion of String into Integer:

```
machine_name = get_val(['kernel']['os_info']['cs_name'], ohai_data, 'n/a')
```

Never finds anything 1, likely because ['kernel']['os_info']['cs_name'] != "['kernel']['os_info']['cs_name']":

```
machine_name = get_val("['kernel']['os_info']['cs_name']", ohai_data, 'n/a')
```

Never finds anything 2, using ohai_data.fetch(val_to_get)
Never finds anything 3, using ohai_data.fetch_values(val_to_get)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you properly, for this case the perfect choice would be `dig` method:

```
ohai_data = JSON.parse(::IO.read(json_file).force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_16))
default_value = 'n/a'

> ohai_data.dig('kernel','os_info','cs_name') || default_value
=> "<the computer name>"

ohai_data.dig('kernel','os_info','cs_other_name') || default_value
=> "n/a"
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig